# objects disappear

Tags: object-mode

When it moves away from large objects, it disappears into the darkness. How can I set the visible distance of objects?[image]

Comment: Hello, in the N panel > View tab, check the Clip End value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to adjust the view clipping limits of the 3D viewport, these settings are available in the right-hand side menu (toggle its visibility with keyboard shortcut `n`).

[image]